# Add attribute to list/grid category page in magento 1.9

Tags: list, magento, grid

I want to add a selector for attribute in magento 1.9, in the list/grid page. I tried some online guide, but don't work with new magento 1.9, can anyone help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

After any changes with products and attributes you first need do reindex. And then check the same code as 1.8. New 1.9 Magento has a problem with reindex after any changes.

Comment: ok thanks, you know any online guide to enter the attributes?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields and call attribute in your list.phtm or view.phtml

<!-- these are regular text attributes -->
  <?php echo $_product->getMyAttribute() ?>
  <?php echo $_product->getAnotherCustomAttribute() ?>
 
<!-- this is dropdown attribute -->
  <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('your_attribute') ?>
 
<!-- this is a boolean attribute -->
  <?php echo $_product->getMyAttributeName() ? "Yes" : "No" ?>